# Calculate cartesian coordinates from lattice points in hexagonal closest packing (HCP)

Tags: geometry

Given the lattice position in a hexagonal closest packing crystal structure, how can I find the corresponding Cartesian coordinate?

Since HCP has two basis vectors, I am unsure how to approach this programmatically.

I found this [resource online](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXoypizjW3WknFiJnKLwHCnL72vedxjQkDDP1mXWo6uco/wiki/Fractional_coordinates.html) but did not yield the correct result with a, b = 1 and c = 1.633 and alpha, beta = 90, gamma = 120.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for solving this problem? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try $\,\textrm{HCP}(i,j,k) =
 (i+(j+m)/2,\, (3j+m)/\sqrt{12},\, k\sqrt{2/3})\,$ where $\,m=\textrm{mod}(k,2)\,$ and $\,i,j,k\,$ are any integers.
Check this with the [OEIS sequence A004012](https://oeis.org/A004012) "Theta series of hexagonal close-packing.". What the formula expresses with the use of $\,m\,$ the parity of $\,k\,$ is that HCP is **not** a lattice but the union of two lattices. The first is centered at the origin and the second is a shifted copy of the first.